# How to store Game state in to the database and load it using php and c# script

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I have to find a way to Save and Load Game state from Database using c# script and php. So far I'm able to store the player location to my local registry but saving it remotely is the problem. Does anyone know the list of steps i need to implement this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class SaveSystem : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public void SaveState () {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        FileStream file = File.Create (Application.persistentDataPath + "/PlayerData.dat");
        PlayerData data = new PlayerData ();

        data.posX = transform.position.x;
        data.posY = transform.position.y;
        data.posZ = transform.position.z;

        data.rotX = transform.eulerAngles.x;
        data.rotY = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        data.rotZ = transform.eulerAngles.z;

        bf.Serialize (file, data);
        file.Close ();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void LoadState () {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/PlayerData.dat")){
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/PlayerData.dat", FileMode.Open);
            PlayerData data = (PlayerData) bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            transform.position = new Vector3(data.posX, data.posY, data.posZ);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(data.rotX, data.rotY, data.rotZ);
        }


         [Serializable]
    class PlayerData{
        public float posX;
        public float posY;
        public float posZ;

        public float rotX;
        public float rotY;
        public float rotZ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so i cannot remember the correct syntax but heres something to get you started so create a php file on your server and create functions for load and save 
and create get variables like this .

```
         if(isset($GET_["save"]){
          SaveFunctionName();
          }
```

Now when you want to send data to your server and call this function do this:

```
   public string url = "Your server url?ur get variable name";
              IEnumerator Start() {
              WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
              form.AddBinaryData("fileUpload", bytes);
               WWW w = new WWW(screenShotURL, form);
               yield return w;
              }
```

Make sure you return back a string from php inside w to check if data was saved or not.

Answer (score 0):

so far i found a way to store player location position X,Y,Z and Rotate X,Y,Z to my database Unity C# script looks something like this would this the most efficient way of implementing it

```
[Serializable]
    class PlayerData{
        public float posX;
        public float posY;
        public float posZ;

        public float rotX;
        public float rotY;
        public float rotZ;

    }

public void SaveState () {
        PlayerData data = new PlayerData ();

        data.posX = transform.position.x;
        data.posY = transform.position.y;
        data.posZ = transform.position.z;

        data.rotX = transform.eulerAngles.x;
        data.rotY = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        data.rotZ = transform.eulerAngles.z;
        //data.posX.ToString ();
        //player = new Player ();


        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("positionX", data.posX.ToString ());
        form.AddField("positionY", data.posY.ToString());
        form.AddField("positionZ", data.posZ.ToString());
        form.AddField("rotateX", data.rotX.ToString());
        form.AddField("rotateY", data.rotY.ToString());
        form.AddField("rotateZ", data.rotZ.ToString());
        WWW w = new WWW("http://localhost:8080/player.php", form);
        StartCoroutine(saved(w));
        //bf.Serialize (file, data);
        //file.Close ();


IEnumerator saved(WWW w)
{
    yield return w;
    if (w.error == null)
    {
        if (w.text == "login-SUCCESS")
        {
            print("WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!");
        }
        else
            message += w.text;
    }
    else
    {
        message += "ERROR: " + w.error + "\n";
    }
}
```

}

create a php file on my server called player which saved my player state in the database

```
    <?PHP

$positionX = $_POST['positionX'];
$positionY = $_POST['positionY'];
$positionZ = $_POST['positionZ'];
$roX = $_POST['rotateX'];
$roY = $_POST['rotateY'];
$roZ = $_POST['rotateZ'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","usbw") or ("Cannot connect!"  . mysql_error());
if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("game" , $con) or die ("could not load the database" . mysql_error()); 



//$pass = md5($pass);
$ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `player` (  `Player_ID`, `positionX` ,  `positionY` ,  `positionZ` ,  `rotateX` ,  `rotateY` ,  `rotateZ`) VALUES ('' , '".$positionX."' ,  '".$positionY."' ,  '".$positionZ."',  '".$roX."' ,  '".$roY."' ,  '".$roZ."') ; ");
        if ($ins)
            die ("Succesfully Created User!");
        else
            die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
    ?>
```